# getting value from radiobutton group that is binded to a managed bean

Tags: java, xpages, xpages-ssjs

On my XPage I have a radio button group control which is binded to a managed bean:

```
<xp:radioGroup value="#{employeeBean.employee.staffMember}" id="radioStaff">
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" />
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="No" />
    <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="radioStaffDept"></xp:eventHandler>
</xp:radioGroup>
```

When set to Yes I would like to display another input field to enter the department.

I have tried to set the visibility via the partial refresh option but I always get the value returned how it is set via my bean.

I tested to collect it's value via:

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
var radio1:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspInputRadio = getComponent("radioStaff");
return radio1.getValue()}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
```

So when loaded and the value is No, if I set the radiobutton to Yes it remains No.

How should I collect the (changed) value from the radiobutton?

Ps I tried adding a binding property (e.g. `binding="#{myValue}"`) but got same undesired result via this method.

PPs I also tried to set the staffMember field on the onChange event but this did not work either (`employeeBean.employee.setStaffMember("Yes");`)

===

I am not sure if I understood it correctly Yes with the following code I can check if a person is a staff member, but how do I write (temporarely) value back to my proposal object in my bean when I change options in the radio button?

```
private Employee employee;

    public Boolean isStaffMember(){
        if (employee.getStaffMember()=="Yes"){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void setStaffMember(String value){
        employee.setStaffMember(value);
    }


  <xp:radioGroup
                            value="#{employeeBean.employee.staffMember}"
                            binding="#{staffMember}" id="radioStaffMember">
                            <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" />
                            <xp:selectItem itemLabel="No" />
                            <xp:eventHandler event="onchange"
                                submit="true" refreshMode="partial"
                                refreshId="pnlStaffMemberDept" >
                                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var thisVal = getComponent("radioStaffMember").getValue();
employeeBean.setStaffMember(thisVal);}]]></xp:this.action>
                            </xp:eventHandler>
                        </xp:radioGroup>
```

Comment: I notice the presence of several checkbox group controls on my form cause the problem. When I remove them the SSJS works as expected. Is this a known bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
<p>Staff member?</p>

<xp:radioGroup value="#{employeeBean.employee.staffMember}"
    id="radioStaff">
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" />
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="No" />
    <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
        execMode="partial" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="examples" />
</xp:radioGroup>

<xp:div id="examples">
    <xp:text disableOutputTag="true"
        rendered="#{not empty employeeBean.employee.staffMember}">
        <p>
            <xp:text value="The value is: #{employeeBean.employee.staffMember}" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <xp:text value="A staff member (checkbox string value evaluation)"
                rendered="#{employeeBean.employee.staffMember eq 'Yes'}" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <xp:text value="A staff member (boolean value evaluation)"
                rendered="#{employeeBean.staffMember}" style="color: green" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <xp:text value="Not a staff member (boolean value evaluation)"
                rendered="#{not employeeBean.staffMember}" style="color: red" />
        </p>
    </xp:text>
</xp:div>
```

And the bean composition. I used a map because I don't know anything about your `Employee` class :) :

```
public class EmployeeBean implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private Map<String, Object> employee;

  public Map<String, Object> getEmployee() {
    if (employee == null) {
        employee = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }

    return employee;
  }

  public boolean isStaffMember() {
        return "Yes".equals(getEmployee().get("staffMember"));
  }

}
```

Some pieces of advice:

1. Try to use as less `javascript` language as you can. It won't help you in the long run. Besides, source is painful to watch. Use EL expressions as much as you can, strive for always
2. Don't compare Java string with == but rather with `.equals`
3. Make sure that the block you want to refresh can actually be refreshed (see why I left the `xp:div id="example` always visible but then added an inner tag that checks on the `staffMember` value). It doesn't mean you will necessarily have to do that. It depends on how you structure your XPage.
4. Narrow the POST scope with `execMode`. Strive for performance

Comment: I do not know what I am doing wrong but in my setter in my Employee class public void setStaffMember(String staffMember) {
  System.out.println("setStaffMember: " + staffMember);
  this.staffMember = staffMember;
 } it constant prints "No" to the console when I change values in the radiobutton.

Comment: can it be that the employeeBean is reloaded with the partial refresh?

Comment: What's the scope of the `employeeBean`? How is it set up in the `faces-config.xml`?
Is there anything else going on with the `Employee` class? Could you post its source code?

Comment: Hi ! I had the initialization of my managed bean in the before render response event by mistake. This should have been in the before pageload event ofcourse. (sorry, I am still learning...) I have implemented your suggestion and it works like charm. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Good to hear. Right management for a bean to be called managed is done through the `faces-config.xml` file

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnawq.html) and keep it handy.

What's important to understand is that the term XPages is misleading: (1) the name hides what's really behind it - JSF - and that doesn't help you do things right since you try to tackle problems the "poor" way IBM presented packaged it. Forget about XPages and think JSF. When you want to understand things or solve problems it gives you more value.

Comment: Ok I will do. Why did IBM educated us a bit more on developing in XPages and understanding the underlying layer (JSF) a bit more? My course never went further than the out of the box controls and data-binding.

Answer (score 0):

You don't go after UI components. For visibility use an EL expression `employeeBean.isStaffMember` that you provide as Boolean method on your bean. 
Just make sure your partial refresh target (a panel?) includes both your radio buttons and the extra fields

Comment: can you help me. I am not sure if I am interpret you correctly. I updated my question with your suggestion.

Comment: if I perform a partial refresh every time the original value (from the Notes document) is loaded when the bean is re-initiated when refreshing the department field :-?

Comment: What you do inside your bean is up to you. I would configure the bean as viewScope scoped and use dedicated load(unid) and save() methods on it

Comment: You wouldn't refresh from the Notes document each time you do a partial refresh - defeats the purpose of a managed bean. You load the values once and you call a save method (using the document as parameter) once you are done.